# Updated version of Mvc Music Store or something similar for VS2017 AspNet Core 2

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, lookup, ef-core-2.0

The mvcmusicstore tutorial appears to answer many of my questions but it was written using VS 2010.

https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=mvcmusicstore

Tutorials written using VS 2015 or before do not always work with VS 2107. I am finding issues like dbcontext refusing to register etc. Microsoft docs for aspnet core Contoso University has been helpful.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/?view=aspnetcore-2.0

I am looking for examples for how to show a name instead of the id using models etc. The names exits in a different table.

The mvc music store is a good tutorial and I would like to find a current version to learn from.

Thanks in advance!
Bill

Comment: There is [mvcmovies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/start-mvc?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-2.2) and do have a look at eShopOnWeb (find it on GitHub)

Answer (score -2):

From another post, the book I found 'Pro Asp.Net Core Mvc 2' by Adam Freeman. It is a book in pure Core and scaffolding is not used. He uses a Sporting Goods Store with a check out etc. So far, it looks promising. He describes processes in detail. Hopefully, he will keep the book updated on GitHub.